# Put a mask over a whole page with canvas or SVG

Tags: javascript, css, html, svg

I am trying to make a mask over a whole page. My solution is to make a transparent png with the shape of the mask and making the borders really big. After that I am putting this over the whole document.

Although I already got the solution, but it looks really dirty to me and is not responsive at all.

Is there a better solution to do this like with canvas, javascript and SVG?

```
.masktest {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9999;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 8000px solid #000;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -8100px;
  margin-left: -8100px;
  background-image: url('img/masktest.png');
}
```

[Here is the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pbec1ukz/12/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make the mask with a pseudo element either `:before` or `:after`.

```css
body { margin: 0; }
body:before {
  content: "";
  position: fixed;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.75) url("https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/mozilla.svg") center / cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
Hello world.
```